# S3 api request from custom domainredirect to default s3 endpoint

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have a domain named example.com and bucket named test in us-east-2 region. I have a .net console app to upload files to S3 bucket using aws s3 nuget package.

I dont want to access amazon urls, so i decided to use the example.com as the service url property of S3 config and set forcepathstyle to true.

I have added url redirect in my dns to send the requests but that is not working. Please help to send requests to S3 from the app without using amazon urls in the application.

Comment: Use FTP to upload.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scripts/powershell-deploy-ftp

Comment: The issue is, this application will be used in client place and only example.com is whitelisted. Acessing aws urls wont work

Comment: 'I dont want to access amazon urls' - can you expand on this please?

Comment: In client place, there is a restriction to access aws url. So i want to use my own domain and then i wanted to redirect the api calls to my own domain to s3

Comment: Redirecting means that it'll still be blocked; that won't work.